# Is there a way to compute the cosets of D<sub>2n</sub> in <i>S</i><sub><i>n</i></sub>

Tags: python, c, math

Although this is a question of maths but I really wanted to figure out if something like this is possible or not by coding it .(preferably in C). I had the question posted in mathsstackexchange where I saw that there's a way to find out the cosets of D_12 in S_6 by using Python programming. Can someone just help me to figure out how are we doing this?

S_n is the group formed by all possible permutations of n-elements and D_2n is formed by the generators `<r, s>` where r =(123, n) and s=(1n)(2 n-1).

Here's the link to the answer

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3880306/find-the-cosets-of-d-2n-in-s-n

Also I am not accustomed to posting questions in stackoverflow, I really don't know how to add mathematical symbols.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The answer you linked already contains python code that appears to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Though the logic remains same, the implementation will vary from Python to c due to difference is data types and so on. So you should try learning Python, it’s very easy to learn and you can pick up writing code in Python within few days considering you already you know a few other languages. And writing such complex programs can be easy in Python due to the vast inbuilt libraries and readability. So it’s better if you learn Python and start implementing this in Python.

Comment: Is it possible to write the programming sage?

Comment: Yes, since sage is Python-based you can write in it.